# Creating a selection line under item when item is selected

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styles

I have been working with a scrollview and a tabview in the same component. I had to create a way to make that work on react. It is working according to expected, although I can't seem to reproduce the following line in my page. I could set it under the component, although the line when selected I couldn't manage to.

[image]

What I have:

[image]

How my code is being done:

```
const tabs = [
  { icon: <FeedSVG width={15} height={15} style={{ marginRight: 10 }} />, text: 'Feeds' },
  { icon: <VideoShortSVG width={15} height={15} style={{ marginRight: 10 }} />, text: 'Shorts' },
  { icon: <TagUnionSVG width={15} height={15} style={{ marginRight: 10 }} />, text: 'Tags' },
];

 return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 30 }}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        {tabs.map((e, i) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <Pressable
                onPress={() => {
                  console.log('pressed', e, i);
                  setSelected(i);
                }}
                style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
              >
                {e.icon}
                <Text style={[styles.title, selected == i && { color: '#00FF' }]}>{e.text}</Text>
              </Pressable>
              {selected == i && <View style={styles.line} />}
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
```

The styles:

```
onst styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: 'gray',
  },
  starCon: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginVertical: 9,
  },
  star: {
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  titleItem: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  item: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  body: {
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    flex: 1,
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
  },
  line: {
    width: 50,
    height: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 3,
  },
  image: {
    width: w / 3.8,
    height: w / 3.8,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  footerItem: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  footerCard: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  footerItemText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'gray',
    marginLeft: 10,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  iconHeart: {
    tintColor: '#000',
  },
  buttonHeart: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 15,
    top: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: cant you increase the width of the line?

Comment: But then all the line is going to be selected

Comment: try width : "100%%

Comment: As I mentioned, this works for setting the line width to 100% but it won't work for the selection items, since the line will be under all the other tabs

Comment: if you can create a snack with this existing issue I can try to come up with a solution. https://snack.expo.dev/